# Json response does not output in view, but prompts me to download the file instead

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jsonp

I am using WebRequest to read JSON data from the FCC so I can output it to a view.  Here is my custom class to hold an FCC license:

```
     public class License
        {
            public string Name{ get; set; }
            public string Frn { get; set; }
            public string Callsign { get; set;}
            public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
            public string ServiceDesc { get; set; }
            public string StatusDesc { get; set; }
            public DateTime ExpiredDate { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string DetailUrl { get; set; }

        }
```

Here is the Controller action that I am using to read the json results.
I have Verizon Wireless hard-coded as the search value for now:

```
public ActionResult GetLicenses()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=jsonp&jsonCallback=?";

            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

            webRequest.Timeout = 2000;

            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (receiveStream != null)
                    {
                        var stream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                        result = stream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return new ContentResult { Content = result, ContentType = "application/json" };

        }
```

Here is the view.  I am trying to enumerate through all the licenses and output them to a table, but when I go to /Home/GetLicenses, it prompts me to download the file:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.License>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Licenses";
}

<h2>Licenses</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Frn
        </th>
        <th>
            Callsign
        </th>
        <th>
            CategoryDesc
        </th>
        <th>
            ServiceDesc
        </th>
        <th>
            StatusDesc
        </th>
        <th>
            ExpiredDate
        </th>
        <th>
            DetailUrl
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Frn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Callsign)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDesc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDesc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusDesc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpiredDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DetailUrl)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I got the above working if I do it directly through jquery's getJSON method, but I wanted to see if I could get the results from a contoller to a view and then have it rendered in the view.

This is a sample of what is returned in the results variable:

```
?({
    "status": "OK",
    "Licenses": {
        "page": "1",
        "rowPerPage": "100",
        "totalRows": "1995",
        "lastUpdate": "Sep 21, 2011",
        "License": [
            {
                "licName": "CELLCO PARTNERSHIP (\"VERIZON WIRELESS\")",
                "frn": "",
                "callsign": "",
                "categoryDesc": "Satellite Earth Station",
                "serviceDesc": "",
                "statusDesc": "Active",
                "expiredDate": "",
                "licenseID": "2300007967",
                "licDetailURL": "http://licensing.fcc.gov/cgi-bin/ws.exe/prod/ib/forms/reports/swr031b.hts?prepare=&column=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number&q_set=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number/=/FCNNEW2000060800036"
            },
            {
                "licName": "CELLO PARTNERSHIP (\"VERIZON WIRELESS\")",
                "frn": "",
                "callsign": "",
                "categoryDesc": "Satellite Earth Station",
                "serviceDesc": "",
                "statusDesc": "Active",
                "expiredDate": "",
                "licenseID": "2300010661",
                "licDetailURL": "http://licensing.fcc.gov/cgi-bin/ws.exe/prod/ib/forms/reports/swr031b.hts?prepare=&column=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number&q_set=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number/=/FCNNEW2000083100048"
            },
            {
                "licName": "Cellco Partnership d/b/a Verizon Wireless",
                "frn": "0003290673",
                "callsign": "KE2XMC",
                "categoryDesc": "Experimental",
                "serviceDesc": "Experimental Developmental",
                "statusDesc": "Unknown",
                "expiredDate": "12/14/2000",
                "licenseID": "3000020853",
                "licDetailURL": "https://fjallfoss.fcc.gov/oetcf/els/reports/ELSSearchResult.cfm?callsign=KE2XMC"
            },
            {
                "licName": "Cellco Partnership d/b/a Verizon Wireless",
                "frn": "0003290673",
                "callsign": "WA2XPS",
                "categoryDesc": "Experimental",
                "serviceDesc": "Experimental Developmental",
                "statusDesc": "Unknown",
                "expiredDate": "12/14/2000",
                "licenseID": "3000020851",
                "licDetailURL": "https://fjallfoss.fcc.gov/oetcf/els/reports/ELSSearchResult.cfm?callsign=WA2XPS"
            },
            {
                "licName": "Cellco Partnership dba Verizon Wireless",
                "frn": "0003290673",
                "callsign": "KNKP866",
                "categoryDesc": "Mobile/Fixed Broadband",
                "serviceDesc": "Cellular",
                "statusDesc": "Cancelled",
                "expiredDate": "10/01/2005",
                "licenseID": "13328",
                "licDetailURL": "http://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/license.jsp?__newWindow=false&licKey=13328"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

I added this class:

```
 public class FCC
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Licenses Licenses { get; set; }

    }
```

But I still get the Invalid JSON primitive.

```
 public ActionResult GetLicenses()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var url =
                "http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=jsonp&jsonCallback=?";

            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

            webRequest.Timeout = 2000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (receiveStream != null)
                    {
                        var stream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                        result = stream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            FCC fcc = new FCC();

            if (result.StartsWith(@"?("))
            {
                result = result.Substring(2);
            }

            if (result.EndsWith(@")"))
            {
                result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
            }


            if (result != null)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                fcc = serializer.Deserialize<FCC>(result);
            }
            return View(fcc.Licenses.License);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning a `ContentResult` from your ActionMethod, your browser is going to respond with the appropriate action based upon the content. In this case a JSON string will be downloaded similar to a file since it is not a HTML doc.

If you want to render the results in a View and not through AJAX, then you will need to create a C# Model class representing your WebRequest response data, and then return a `ViewResult` and pass the model (or collection of models) to the View.

I would suggest changing your `ActionMethod` to do something like below, and also create a View called "Licenses"

Also, your example response is a bit of a trick. It is more complex than an array of your original License Object, AND it is wrapped with a `?()`. The JavaScriptSerializer will only deserialize properties that it can match based on property name (it is case sensitive as well). And because of the `?()` wrapping, we need to remove that so the deserialization won't break.

So you would need to modify your License object accordingly:

```
public class FCC
{
    public string status {get;set;}
    public Licenses Licenses {get; set;}
}
public class License
{
    public string licName{ get; set; }
    public string frn { get; set; }
    public string callsign { get; set;}
    public string categoryDesc { get; set; }
    public string serviceDesc { get; set; }
    public string statusDesc { get; set; }
    public string expiredDate { get; set; } //JSON dates and C# Dates are very finicky
    public string licenseID { get; set; }
    public string licDetailURL { get; set; }
}

public class Licenses
{
    public int page {get; set;}
    public int rowPerPage {get; set;}
    public int totalRows {get; set;}
    public string lastUpdate {get; set;}
    public List<License> License {get; set;}
}


public ActionResult Licenses()
{
        var result = string.Empty;
        var url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=jsonp&jsonCallback=?";

        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

        webRequest.Timeout = 2000;

        using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (receiveStream != null)
                {
                    var stream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                    result = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        FCC fcc = new FCC();

        if (result.StartsWith(@"?("))
        {
            result = result.Substring(2);
        }

        if (result.EndsWith(@")"))
        {
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
        }

        if(result != null)
        {
             JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             fcc = serializer.Deserialize<FCC>(result);
        }
        return View(fcc.Licenses.License); //pass the data that your view needs

}
```

Lastly, you will need to change the property names in your CSHTML file, since the new License object doesn't have the same property names anymore.

AJAX is probably another question, but I'll post back here if I run across a good example

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying.  I need to convert my response to a collection of c# objects and then pass that model to the view to be rendered.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Alternatively, how would I do it through AJAX?

Comment: I tried the above but I get the error message: Invalid JSON primitive: .

Comment: Can you post an example response from your WebRequest? like what does the result variable look like when you are debugging?

Comment: I updated my post with sample data that is returned.  I omitted licenses so it wouldn't be so long.

Comment: I also must not that I had to put licenses outside the if statement because it did not find it in View(licenses) when it was inside the if block.

Comment: updated my response... the real trick here is getting your C# object model setup to match the JSON response that you are getting, once you do that, then the rest should fall into place

Comment: I still get Invalid JSON primitive.  Do I need to change the model my view is bound to as well?

Comment: No the JSON primitive error should still be related to the JavaScriptSerializer, try creating a model that houses `Licenses` and has a `status` property

Comment: it was the `?()` wrapping on your JSON response that was tripping us up, this deserialization works.

Comment: EricB, thanks a lot for your patience.  That was it.  I now need to fix the ugly formatting of the table :).  Do you think it was only those characters or do you think I still need to have the 3 models I created, FCC, Licenses, and License.

Comment: The characters were the reason the deserialization weren't working. If you want to deserialize into C# objects, then yes, you will need to keep the `FCC`, `Licenses`, and `License` objects. However, if you want to skip down and only pull out the parts that you would like check out JSON.NET, I believe it has a LinqToJSON implementation

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code which I will try to address:

1. You have a controller action which returns a JSON string and you have defined some Razor view but this razor view is never invoked from the action.
2. You are querying a remote service which returns JSONP instead of using the JSON possibility of the API which seems more adapted.
3. You are jeopardizing a worker thread during the fetching of the remote resource.

So let's start by our view models:

```
public class License
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Frn { get; set; }
    public string Callsign { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDesc { get; set; }
    public string StatusDesc { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiredDate { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DetailUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Licenses
{
    public License[] License { get; set; }
}

public class FCC
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Licenses Licenses { get; set; }
}
```

then we would have the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = client.DownloadString("http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=json");
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var model = serializer.Deserialize<FCC>(json);
            return View(model.Licenses.License);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how in the url I am no longer specifying the `jsonCallback` querystring parameter which is intended to be used with JSONP and I don't want JSONP, I want JSON. For that matter I have also set the `format=json` parameter.

And finally we could have the following `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<License>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Frn
            </th>
            <th>
                Callsign
            </th>
            <th>
                CategoryDesc
            </th>
            <th>
                ServiceDesc
            </th>
            <th>
                StatusDesc
            </th>
            <th>
                ExpiredDate
            </th>
            <th>
                DetailUrl
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the corresponding display template which will be rendered for each element of the Licenses collection (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/License.cshtml`):

```
@model License

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Frn)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Callsign)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CategoryDesc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ServiceDesc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.StatusDesc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ExpiredDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DetailUrl)
    </td>
</tr>
```

OK, so far we have addresses point 1. and 2.

Now the third one. The problem with this synchronous call is the following line: `client.DownloadString`. This is a blocking call. Blocking calls on remote resources are very bad in ASP.NET applications. Here you are fetching some remote resource which could take time => you will be traversing network boundaries, internet firewalls, ... until you hit the remote web server which itself, in order to serve the request will query a database, ... You get the point: it is slow. And during all this time your web application is sitting and waiting and a thread was monopolized. Remember that you have a limited number of worker threads at your disposal so don't waste them.

The way to solve this [very serious issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) is to use [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) and I/O Completion Ports. Those are built directly into windows kernel and allow you to perform IO intensive operations without blocking and monopolizing threads on your server.

Here's how your HomeController will become:

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    public void IndexAsync()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                AsyncManager.Parameters["error"] = e.Error.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var model = serializer.Deserialize<FCC>(e.Result);
                AsyncManager.Parameters["licenses"] = model.Licenses.License;
            }
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=json"));
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(License[] licenses, string error)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("licenses", error);
        }
        return View(licenses ?? Enumerable.Empty<License>());
    }
}
```

Comment: I will review this when I get a chance.  Thanks for the insight Darin.

Comment: Darin, I looked over the points you made. I right clicked on the controller and selected Add View and created a View called GetLicenses.cshtml which was created under /Home, so I am a little confused when you say the View is not invoked by the controller.  Regarding blocking calls, in case like this is it better to just retreive the json data and parse it via javascript instead of going through a controller action?

Comment: @Xaisoft, you created a view on the disk but never called this view in your Licenses controller action. You returned Json, not View. Regarding the blocking calls there is no single answer. If you are going to use a controller action to fetch remote resources, async controllers are best. If the remote resource supports JSONP (which in your case it does) you could also do the same purely on the client side but if you wanted to present the results in a nice manner you will have to built the DOM manually from the results or use a client templating engine such as jquery.templates.

Comment: I thought this line: return View(fcc.Licenses.License) is returning a View with my JSON model inside to the View I rendered when I added one.

Comment: @Xaisoft, yes exactly, it's just that I can't see this line in your `GetLicenses` action. You are returning `new ContentResult` and not View.

Comment: oh, my fault, I did not update the post. Let me do that and let me know what you think then.  I added the revised method at the bottom of the post.  It still doesn't address the issue of blocking calls and the json format, but I just wanted to make sure I am not going crazy when I think it is passing it to the view when it is actually not.

Comment: @Xaisoft, now that looks better. Well, at least you are passing a view model to the view. The error you are getting is with all this `@"?("` useless stuff that you are trying to parse. Simply follow the url in my example and request JSON from the remote server and not JSONP. Everything will work out of the box then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did and its showing me Json data in DIV...

## Your Controller...

```
public JsonResult GetLicenses()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            const string url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=jsonp&jsonCallback=?";

            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

            webRequest.Timeout = 2000;

            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (receiveStream != null)
                    {
                        var stream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                        result = stream.ReadToEnd();

                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

make the return type Json and type JsonResult in Action

and if you want to call this through AJAX then here is the

## $.ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetLicenses","Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#content').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

and make sure that you reference the Jquery files in _Layout.cshtml..

Comment: I tried this already and it still prompts to download the file.

Comment: in your view you have to call controller action through $.ajax and parse the json data in success callback...

Comment: what if I do not want to use ajax, but instead want to pass the model to the view and have it rendered through razor syntax to a table.

Comment: I also tried the ajax example you gave and it still asks me to download the file.

Comment: well, you must be doing something wrong ... as i tried i am having a perfect Json result rendered in my view....can you post again your controller and jquery please...

Comment: I copied your exact controller method and your exact view.